# ¿Por qué loco translate no encuentra los textos de un array?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Tengo este array:

```
$months_of_year = array(
  __('January','mgm'),
  __('February','mgm'),
  __('March','mgm'),
  __('April','mgm'),
  __('May','mgm'),
  __('June','mgm'),
  __('July','mgm'),
  __('August','mgm'),
  __('September','mgm'),
  __('October','mgm'),
  __('November','mgm'),
  __('December','mgm')
);
```

Y me he introducido ahí la función de traducción de cadena porque se supone que devuelve un string. Sin embargo, loco translate no me encuentra la cadena para traducir, ¿por qué? ¿esta acaso mal el planteamiento?

Gracias por la ayuda!!

Comment: ¿Eso es un plugin?  Quizá deberías preguntar en el foro de soporte del mismo, donde los desarrolladores (o los usuarios) podrán darte mejores respuestas.

Comment: Loco translate es un plugin que hace la funcion de poedit. Es decir, es correcta esta forma, no? wordpress lo aceptaría, no? quiero decir tiene que ser del plugin, no?